# Recieving error "bc: command not found" when calling bash script from Python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script called `filter.sh` and I am calling it within a python script with following code:

```
    subprocess.check_call(["filter.sh", "performance.log"], shell=True)
```

However, I am receiving error:

`bash: bc: command not found`

Note: `bc` command is used in the script. However, the script works all fine in the terminal and running it directly, why can it not find the command when running it from Python script?

Comment: Add full path to `bc` command in your script filter.sh.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for your comment. The path seems to be `/usr/bin/bc`. To clarify what you mean by "add full path"

AVG=$(bc <<<"scale=3; $TOTAL / $COUNT")


Should I replace "bc" with that path here `/usr/bin/bc`?

Comment: Yes. use `/usr/bin/bc`.

Comment: It seems somehow /usr/bin was removed from $PATH. Take a look at filter.sh and put `echo $PATH` just before call to `bc`

Comment: Please look into why `/usr/bin` is not in your PATH instead of trying to treat the symptom by using absolute path.